# How can I know the key of my array when I know the value?

Tags: php, arrays, search, key

I have a multiple-array :

```
$bouton["modify-customer"] = array("fr"=>"liste-client", "en"=>"customer-list");
$bouton["create-customer"] = array("fr"=>"creer-client", "en"=>"create-customer");
$bouton["modify-item"] = array("fr"=>"liste-item", "en"=>"item-list");
$bouton["create-item"] = array("fr"=>"creer-item", "en"=>"create-item");
$bouton["modify-taxes"] = array("fr"=>"liste-taxes", "en"=>"taxes-list");
$bouton["create-taxes"] = array("fr"=>"creer-taxes", "en"=>"create-taxes");
```

In a page, I have this string : "**liste-taxes**"

I need to find : "**taxes-list**"

How can I achieve this task? ...

I know that I need to find the right key here, and it's  **modify-taxes** then I will probably be able to find the other value not the `fr` one, but the `en` one.

I know I'm not super-clear and my English is not very good but I hope you guys can help me, I will stay on the site so I will be able to answer your question and talk with you in the futur comments.

Thanks.

Comment: print_r($bouton['modify-taxes']['en']) ?

Comment: I don't know that it's $bouton['modify-taxes'], I only know "liste-taxes" so I need to find the good key of the array so I can after this do what you said : print_r($bouton['modify-taxes']['en'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to loop through the array and search for the value like so:

```
foreach($bouton as $key => $array){
    if( in_array("liste-taxes",$array)){
        echo $key . PHP_EOL;
        echo $bouton[$key]['en'];
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
modify-taxes 
taxes-list
```

Answer (score 1):

```
array_walk($bouton, function ($val) use ($searched, $lang, &$result) {
    if (in_array($searched, $val))
        $result = $val[$lang];
});
```

where `$searched` is the string you search, `$lang` the language you search. `$result` will contain the final value.

Example:

```
$bouton["modify-customer"]      = array("fr"=>"liste-client", "en"=>"customer-list");
$bouton["create-customer"]  = array("fr"=>"creer-client", "en"=>"create-customer");
$bouton["modify-item"]          = array("fr"=>"liste-item", "en"=>"item-list");
$bouton["create-item"]      = array("fr"=>"creer-item", "en"=>"create-item");
$bouton["modify-taxes"]     = array("fr"=>"liste-taxes", "en"=>"taxes-list");
$bouton["create-taxes"]     = array("fr"=>"creer-taxes", "en"=>"create-taxes");

$searched = "liste-taxes";
$lang = "en";

array_walk($bouton, function ($val) use ($searched, $lang, &$result) {
    if (in_array($searched, $val))
        $result = $val[$lang];
});

print $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over your array and find the translation:

```
$search = "liste-taxes";

$bouton["modify-customer"]      = array("fr"=>"liste-client", "en"=>"customer-list");
$bouton["create-customer"]  = array("fr"=>"creer-client", "en"=>"create-customer");
$bouton["modify-item"]          = array("fr"=>"liste-item", "en"=>"item-list");
$bouton["create-item"]      = array("fr"=>"creer-item", "en"=>"create-item");
$bouton["modify-taxes"]     = array("fr"=>"liste-taxes", "en"=>"taxes-list");
$bouton["create-taxes"]     = array("fr"=>"creer-taxes", "en"=>"create-taxes");

array_walk($bouton, function($v, $i) use($search) {
   if($v['fr'] === $search) {
       echo $v['en'];
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a handy translate function....

```
function translate($array, $searchterm, $lan){
foreach($array as $key => $array){
if( in_array($searchterm,$array)){
    return $array[$lan];
}}}
```

And then just pass it the array, the term, and the language, 
and you'll get the fr, or en version depending on what you specify.

```
  echo translate($bouton,"taxes-list","fr");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($bouton as $key => $array){
    if( in_array("taxes-list",$array)){
        echo $key . PHP_EOL;
        echo $bouton[$key]['en'];
    }
}
```

Thaks to immulatin, phpisubuer01 and bwoebi !!! Work's like a charm.